# Which PassportJS authentication strategy for both login and without login APIs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, passport.js

I am building an android application as client and a hapijs framework/Mongodb as my back-end.
In my application reading most data must be accessible without login and when user want to write something to app has to login and be authorized.
My security concern is that if I don't use any authentication for APIs without login it may causes DDOS attack or some hacker force my server to do extra processes.
I think a solution is to accept requests only from my application but I am not sure this is possible or not.
And I also don't know which one of PassportJS strategies is good for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can user passport-local npm module for authentication in node but for non-authenticated service you can use "API_KEY" and also can generate unique "API_TOKEN" to authorize the requests from your application only.

Comment: what if a hacker install my apk and sniff packets then he can call my API anywhere with the token?

Comment: No hacker will not be able to call your API anywhere until he get the source code of your application.